# Facebook automated wishing.

Tags: facebook

I am trying to create an automated way to wish everyone who has liked my facebook page a happy birthday on the day of their birthday. I want this to be automatic and a private message. Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: That is not possible. You can't get their birthday or message them just because they liked your page

Comment: @WizKid how do you know that?

Comment: Because the documentation say so on developers.facebook.com/docs and I work at Facebook.

Comment: @WizKid is it possible for me to visit everyone who has liked my page and get their birthdates? Is that public information?

Comment: No it is not possible. The API doesn't have it and you are not allowed to scrape Facebook

Comment: @WizKid Can you email me so I can ask you a few more questions? garg.bhanu1@gmail.com

Comment: No. If you have questions you can post them here

Comment: @WizKid can I pm everyone who likes my page?

Comment: Of course not. If you want to say something to people that liked your page then post on your page

Comment: @WizKid so there is no may for me to auto message everyone who has liked my page the same message

Comment: That is what the "of course not" part answered